# I've never thought of it that way

Tags: present-perfect

> I've never thought of it that way.

Does this sentence have two different interpretations depending on different contexts?

> You're telling me a new perspective of thinking it. It's wonderful. I've never thought of it that way until now. I'll begin to think of it that way now.

> You're telling me a new perspective of thinking it. But it sounds absurd. You ask me, "have you ever thought of it that way?" I reply, "no, never. I've never thought of it that way, and I won't take into account your new idea."

Comment: Obviously the meaning depends on context. The two possibilities you've given won't be the *only* possible interpretations for the cited text, but they're certainly a start.

Comment: Exactly. I don't see there being two completely separate, opposite meanings. "Well, I've never thought of it that way, but you could be right."

Comment: I'm not sure how those are really two different *interpretations* of the statement.  The statement by itself doesn't really imply anything about whether you like the new way or not.

Comment: @Stephen it could also mean "I've never even considered it before".

Comment: Agree with @strangdon. The tone with which the sentence is delivered can imply where the speaker places himself on the spectrum of possible reactions.

Answer (score 2):

"*I've never thought of it that way*" means that you have applied a new way of thinking to something specific ("it"). In isolation, there are no other implications, such as whether the new view of the thing is positive or negative, or whether the hearer agrees with that view or not. Such details would have to be explained in the wider context, or else remain ambiguous.

Generally though, saying "I've never thought of it that way" comes over as an admission that you had omitted to consider that particular angle. It would seem a little odd to admit that and then immediately reject it.